# How to make a request and return a response with Express in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I trying to send a request to an api and return the response with express when someone curl my site.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    request.get('the_api')
  .on('response', function(resp){
    return res.status(200).send({
      text: resp.body
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For that requirement, in my projects I use `axios`, from the documentation:

Axio is a promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js.

Here is a complete example:

```
const axios = require('axios');
// api openexchange
const oexchange = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/',
    timeout: 60000
})
oexchange.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.params = config.params || {};
    config.params.app_id = 'myapitoken'
    return config;
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            //here it will request:
            //https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=myapitoken
            req.oexchange = await oexchange.get('latest.json')
            return res.status(200).json(req.oexchange.data)
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: 'cotacao', msg: 'Houve um erro ao acessar a api do open exchange.', param: 'openexchangerates' }] })
        }
})
```

In my example I am requesting an external exchange api.

Here is the [documentation from axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Hope it helps.